# Code Performance Tuning

Tags: performance-tuning

The following code takes over 4 seconds to run. Any one has suggestions to make the expressions for `qf`, `phi`, `qr`, and `k` more efficient?

Can someone suggest ways I can use`NestWhile` in the place of `While` and `Compile[]` on the four expressions (`qf`, `phi`, `qr`, and `k`) to enable `Parallelization`?

```
demand[n_, k_] := Min[k Vf, n capacity];
supply[n_, k_] := Min[(n Kj - k) w, n capacity];
flo[n_, ku_, kd_] := Min[demand[n, ku], supply[n, kd]];
gamma[ku_, kd_] := Min[1, supply[L, kd]/demand[L, ku]];
inflow [phi_, FQin_] := (phi - \[Beta] FQin) dx;
density[qin_, qout_, qr_] := (qin - qout + qr)/Vf;

L = 1; \[Beta] = 0.1; dx = 1/6; capacity = 7500; Kj = 150.; w = 100.; Vf = 100.;TT=0; RML = 2
k0 = Table[1, {i1, 1, 10}];
kr = Table[Table[1, {i1, 1, 4}], {i2, 1, 10}];
While[TT < 200000,
   qf = Map[flo[L, #[[1]], #[[2]]] &, Partition[k0, 2, 1]];
   phi = Flatten[Map[demand[1, #] &, Take[kr, All, -1]]][[2 ;; -2]]*Map[gamma[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, Partition[k0[[2 ;; -1]], 2, 1]];
   qr = (inflow @@ #) & /@ Transpose[{phi, qf[[1 ;; -2]]}];
   k = (Plus @@ #) & /@ Transpose[{Insert[Map[density[#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]] &, Flatten /@ Transpose[{Partition[qf, 2, 1], qr}]], 0, {{1}, {-1}}], k0}];
   k0 = k;
   TT += Plus @@ k0;
]; // Timing
```

**Edit:**

I also have the following piece of code that will go right below the k0=k in the above code

```
RMori = Table[100 (i1 dx)^2 + 50 (i1 dx) + 1000, {i1, 1, n - 2}];
RM = MapThread[Min[#1, #2] &, {RMori, flo[1, #[[RML]], #[[RML + 1]]] & /@ kr}];
qr = MapThread[Join[#1, {#2}, #3, {#4}] &, {flo[L, ##] & @@@ Partition[#[[;; RML]], 2, 1] & /@ kr, RM, flo[L, ##] & @@@ Partition[#[[RML + 1 ;;]], 2, 1] & /@ kr, \[Phi]}];
kr = MapThread[(#1 + #2) &, {Join[{0}, #] & /@ (density[Most@#,Rest@#, 0] & /@ qr), kr}];
```

in line of the suggestions made by SimonWoods, Can some one suggest ways to improve this piece of code?

Also, I need some guidance on using `NestWhile` in place of `While`.

Comment: The initial value for `TT` is missing

Comment: @belisarius Fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you should do is take advantage of [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) functions where possible. For example your `inflow` and `density` functions are composed of Listable functions and are therefore themselves Listable. Also make sure you are not computing the same constant over and over again in a loop (for example the first term in `phi`).

The following is the same calculation as your loop but runs about twice as fast:

```
phi1 = demand[1, #] & /@ kr[[2 ;; -2, -1]];

While[TT < 200000,
   qf = MapThread[flo[L, ##] &, {Most@k0, Rest@k0}];
   phi = phi1 MapThread[gamma, {k0[[2 ;; -2]], k0[[3 ;;]]}];
   qr = inflow[phi, Most@qf];
   k0 += Join[{0}, density[Most@qf, Rest@qf, qr], {0}];
   TT += Total@k0;]; // Timing
```

For a significant speed up you probably need to use `Compile` or significantly restructure the algorithm.

Comment: Excellent points. `Listable` functions is a great idea. I want to use `compile`, but do not know how to do it. Can you please give me some hints.Moreover, I think `Total` is not a CompilerFunction and hence need to use `Plus`.

Comment: Some tips here: [Making Mathematica faster with Compile](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=3635)